# SQL: Cascading conditions on Join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have found a few similar questions to this on SO but nothing which applies to my situation.

I have a large dataset with hundreds of millions of rows in Table 1 and am looking for the most efficient way to run the following query. **I am using Google BigQuery but I think this is a general SQL question applicable to any DBMS?**

I need to apply an owner to every row in Table 1. I want to join in the following priority:

1: if item_id matches an identifier in Table 2

2: if no item_id matches try match on item_name

3: if no item_id or item_name matches try match on item_division

4: if no item_division matches, return null

**Table 1 - Datapoints:**

```
| id | item_id | item_name | item_division | units | revenue
|----|---------|-----------|---------------|-------|---------
| 1  |   xyz   |  pen      |      UK       |   10  |   100
| 2  |   pqr   |  cat      |      US       |   15  |   120
| 3  |   asd   |  dog      |      US       |   12  |   105
| 4  |   xcv   |  hat      |      UK       |   11  |   140
| 5  |   bnm   |  cow      |      UK       |   14  |   150
```

**Table 2 - Identifiers:**

```
| id |  type   |  code     | owner | 
|----|---------|-----------|-------|
| 1  |   id    |  xyz      |  bob  |  
| 2  |   name  |  cat      |  dave |    
| 3  | division|  UK       | alice |    
| 4  |   name  |  pen      | erica |      
| 5  |   id    |  xcv      | fred  |
```

**Desired output:**

```
| id | item_id | item_name | item_division | units | revenue | owner |
|----|---------|-----------|---------------|-------|---------|-------|
| 1  |   xyz   |  pen      |      UK       |   10  |   100   |  bob  | <- id
| 2  |   pqr   |  cat      |      US       |   15  |   120   |  dave | <- code
| 3  |   asd   |  dog      |      US       |   12  |   105   |  null | <- none
| 4  |   xcv   |  hat      |      UK       |   11  |   140   |  fred | <- id
| 5  |   bnm   |  cow      |      UK       |   14  |   150   | alice | <- division
```

My attempts so far have involved multiple joining the table onto itself and I fear it is becoming hugely inefficient.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Oracle, or BigQuery?

Comment: Use three `LEFT JOIN`s with the `Identifiers` table, and `COALESCE()` to select the first non-null value returned in your priority order.

Comment: Yes thanks for that I have been using SO regularly for 6 years. I have tried various solutions for this but am concerned about their efficiency at scale. Am trying your suggestion now, thanks.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> Oracle <> BigQuery!!!

Comment: Have removed the other tags.

Comment: For efficiency, make sure you have indexes on each of the columns that you want to match.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a)[OFFSET(0)].*, 
  ARRAY_AGG(owner 
    ORDER BY CASE 
      WHEN type = 'id' THEN 1
      WHEN type = 'name' THEN 2
      WHEN type = 'division' THEN 3
    END  
    LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)] owner
FROM Datapoints a
JOIN Identifiers b
  ON (a.item_id = b.code AND b.type = 'id')
   OR (a.item_name = b.code AND b.type = 'name')
   OR (a.item_division = b.code AND b.type = 'division')
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id
```

It leaves out entries which k=have no owners  - like in below result (id=3 is out as it has no owner)

```sql
Row id  item_id item_name   item_division   units   revenue owner    
1   1   xyz     pen         UK              10      100     bob  
2   2   pqr     cat         US              15      120     dave     
3   4   xcv     hat         UK              11      140     fred     
4   5   bnm     cow         UK              14      150     alice
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following query (thanks @Barmar) but want to know if there is a more efficient way in Google BigQuery:

```
SELECT a.*, COALESCE(b.owner,c.owner,d.owner) owner FROM datapoints a
LEFT JOIN identifiers b on a.item_id = b.code and b.type = 'id'
LEFT JOIN identifiers c on a.item_name = c.code and c.type = 'name'
LEFT JOIN identifiers d on a.item_division = d.code and d.type = 'division'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if BigQuery optimizes today a query like this - but at least you would be writing a query that gives strong hints to not run the subqueries when not needed:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COALESCE(
  null
  , (SELECT MIN(payload) 
     FROM `githubarchive.year.2016` 
     WHERE actor.login=a.user)
  , (SELECT MIN(payload) 
     FROM `githubarchive.year.2016` 
     WHERE actor.id = SAFE_CAST(user AS INT64))
)
FROM (SELECT '15229281' user) a


4.2s elapsed, 683 GB processed
{"action":"started"}
```

For example, the following query took a long time to run, but BigQuery could optimize its execution massively in the future (depending on how frequently users needed an operation like this):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COALESCE(
  "hello"
  , (SELECT MIN(payload) 
     FROM `githubarchive.year.2016` 
     WHERE actor.login=a.user)
  , (SELECT MIN(payload) 
     FROM `githubarchive.year.2016` 
     WHERE actor.id = SAFE_CAST(user AS INT64))
)
FROM (SELECT actor.login user FROM `githubarchive.year.2016` LIMIT 10) a


114.7s elapsed, 683 GB processed
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```